# When is it impossible for Python to determine the type of the object before runtime?

Tags: python, oop, python-internals, dynamic-typing

One of the downfalls of dynamic typing is the inability to know types before runtime. But it seems to me like given the complete source code, there should be some (possibly not developed yet) way to test each situation in the code so there's less of a chance of runtime crashing. When is this not possible?

Comment: No. There's no such thing as "before runtime" for Python - it's interpreted.

Comment: @erip - I know, it would be something like linting.

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but you might be interested in [function annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/).

Comment: @erip that's cool - it seems like a linter should be able to do this automatically though, no? Or is it actually impossible?

Comment: I think it's impossible because of the nature of interpreted languages - they aren't preprocessed. It's a single pass over the code.

Comment: @erip - then how about in static typing? We still need type declarations. But it seems like Java for example could do without binding types to variables. But supposedly, in a statically typed language, it's impossible - I don't know why.

Comment: It's not a single pass, Python is first compiled to bytecode, which is then interpreted.

Comment: @erip, there are certainly interpreted languages with less maleable typing than Python's (heck, there's an interpreter available for C). It's not about compilation vs interpretation, it's about the language spec purposely being built with duck typing in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another situation where type inference would be ambiguous is if an entire program consisted of

```
def foo(x):
    return x * 3
```

In this case, any type that implements `__mul__` would be a candidate for this. Out of the builtins, this includes `int`, `float`, `complex`, `long`, `list`, `tuple`, `string`, `unicode`, `bytearray`, `buffer`, etc.

If we add more context to our previous example, it becomes clearer how type inference would work:

```
def foo(x):
    return x * 3

y = "hello"
foo(y) #=> "hellohellohello"
```

In this case, we could perform this check simply by using [copy propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_propagation), where we see we're passing in `y`, which we know contains `"hello"`, to `foo`, and therefore, in this case, `foo(x)` would be inferred to be `foo(x: string) -> string`.

Unfortunately, as @Pablo indicated, as soon as we add a conditional, inferring the type once again becomes ambiguous:

```
def foo(x):
    return x * 3

y = "hello"

if some_other_function():
    y = 3

foo(y) #=> 9 or "hellohellohello"???
```

In this case, the best we can say is it's either a `string` or an `int`. Due to adding this conditional (based on the result of `some_other_function()`), we don't know if we'll reach `foo(y)`, and if we do, we don't know what type `y` will be.

In JavaScript (another duck-typed language with a weaker type system than Python), tools such as Facebook's [Flow](http://flowtype.org/) can perform reasonable static type checking. Flow supports type annotations to further aid its analysis, but works well without them. Similarly, function annotations in Python 3 could certainly aid this sort of static analysis. Even without annotations, though, type checking tools like this seem to already exist (See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470/are-there-any-static-analysis-tools-for-python). An example of this is [PySonar2](https://github.com/yinwang0/pysonar2).

Lastly, Python certainly *could* perform this inference. The fact that Python is interpreted means nothing in this context. OCaml has an interpreter that ships with the compiler, yet OCaml is a statically typed language.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this:

```
def aFunction(textInput):
    if textInput == "I want a number this time":
        return 10
    else:
        return "a string"


value = aFunction(input("Type something\n"))
print(type(value))
```

The type of the return value of the function depends on the input.

Also, consider this:

```
def anotherFunction(textInput):
    if isInputValid(textInput):
        return transformTheInputSomehow(textInput);
    else:
        return None
```

`None` actually has a class in Python (`NoneType`)